# Зависание при заезде виджета за край экрана

Tags: c++, qt, видео, qt5

Доброе время суток. Сразу к делу:

Платформа: Windows

Описание: Есть `QWidget` поверх которого показывается видео с помощью MPlayer `("-wid" + QString::number( m_VideoWorkspace->getVideoWidget()->winId() )`. MPlayer запускается через `QProcess`.

Все хорошо показывает и адекватно работает. Но!
Суть проблемы: При перемещении виджета по экрану, в случае захода его края за пределы монитора - приложение виснет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто-то с этим сталкивался - как лечить?

**Обновление**

Использую такие аргументы:

```
QStringList mPlayer_args;
mPlayer_args << "-slave";
mPlayer_args << "-wid" << QString::number( m_VideoWorkspace->getVideoWidget()->winId() );
mPlayer_args << "-cache" << "1024";
mPlayer_args << "-fps" << "600";
mPlayer_args << "-vo" << "direct3d";
mPlayer_args << "-panscan" << "1.0";
mPlayer_args << "-demuxer" << "h264es";
mPlayer_args << "-framedrop";
mPlayer_args << "-nosound";
```

Думаю, Вы правы, и стоит переписать все на OpenGL (использовать кадры как текстуру) тогда проблем быть, в теории, не должно

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас в качестве вывода определён DirectX, то попробуйте сменить его на OpenGL. Либо наоборот. Для mplayer'а - это параметр `-vo`. Чтобы получить список поддерживаемых устройств вывода, используйте команду:

```
mplayer -vo help
```

... однако совместное использование с `-wid`, судя по документации к mplayer'у, поддерживается только для X11 (Linux), OpenGL и DirectX.